# Having Issues creating a loop for HTML table in code and assigning cells for table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a data-source and a table that I have created in HTML in VB.net code.  I have created the cells for the table, but I'm having issues creating multiple cells and the counter for this.  I want to have six cells per row with unlimited rows.  I know I have to add a counter that keeps track of how many cells I've added, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I'm also only getting one cell for my table with the following code.  Please help and let me know what I'm not adding in.

```
       Dim strTable as New StringBuilder()
    strTable.Append("<table Style='border:2;border-width: 1px;'>")

    For Each dr As DataRowView In dv

        Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
        Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
        Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()


        strTable.Append("<tr>")
        For i As Integer = 5 - 1 To 0 Step -1

            strTable.Append(String.Format("<td>'<a href=Breakdown.aspx?p=" + crossover + "'</a>"))
            strTable.Append(String.Format("<img src='Images/" + picid + ".png' width='100' height='100'<br/>"))
            strTable.Append(String.Format(picdescrip + "</td>"))


        Next

        strTable.Append("</tr>")

    Next

    strTable.Append("</table>")
    divTable.InnerHtml = Convert.ToString(strTable)
End Sub
```

Comment: What you currently have is not generating valid HTML, all opened tags should be closed, all attributes should be properly quoted.
And as it is now String.Format is not used and only gives unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example I don't see why you would need to keep track of the number of cells, as it is now you only add one cell with data from crossover, And the cell is name based witch means you will need to type them out.

There is no declaration of strTable, but table is added multiple times, Here is what I would start with:

```
    ' If dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then - Not needed since we will get no data from For Each '
    Dim sbTable as New System.Text.StringBuilder() ' Faster then concating many strings '
    For Each dr As DataRowView In dv

        Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
        Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
        Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()

        sbTable.Append("<tr><td>" & crossover & "</td></tr>") ' Add one line, Separate <tr>, <td> & data & </td>, </tr> to separate lines to add multiple cells '

    Next
    If sbTable.Length > 0 Then divTable.InnerHtml = "<table style=""border:2;border-width: 1px;"">" & sbTable.ToString() & "</table>"
```

StringBuilder is faster then just String if adding many times.
Use & to add string together in VB.NET, this ensure it is added as strings and not something else.

**Edit:** ok so you want to have a grid, It is not exactly clear how you want the output since the generated HTML in your example is not valid and is cut-of in several places. But I will give it a try anyway.
Unfortunatly the markup of VB comments do not work correctly on StackOverflow ( ' at end of comments is to work around that).

```
Dim strTable as New StringBuilder()
Dim itmCounter As Integer = 0
Dim rowIsOpen As Boolean = False
For Each dr As DataRowView In dv

    Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
    Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
    Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()

    ' For every 5 items create a new row. '
    If itmCounter Mod 5 = 0 Then
        ' Since we want new row, first close any open row '
        If rowIsOpen Then strTable.Append("</tr>")

        ' Start a new row and mark row as open so we can keep track '
        strTable.Append("<tr>")
        rowIsOpen = True
    End If


    strTable.Append("<td><a href=""Breakdown.aspx?p=" & crossover & """>")
    strTable.Append("<img src=""Images/" + picid + ".png"" width=""100"" height=""100"" /><br />"))
    strTable.Append(picdescrip & "</a></td>")

    itmCounter += 1

Next

' Make sure we close any open rows '
If rowIsOpen Then strTable.Append("</tr>")

If sbTable.Length > 0 Then
    divTable.InnerHtml = "<table style=""border:2;border-width: 1px;"">" & _
        sbTable.ToString() & _
        "</table>"
End If
```

The `If itmCounter Mod 5 = 0 Then` part is used to close and open a new `tr` every 5 items.
This is needed since `For Each dr` is what changes the items. (instead of looping over the same item 5 times)

I have also made sure the HTML is valid, however you would possibly still want to add some kind of htmlEncode to the values to be sure that no invalid html is generated from incorrect values. ( the double "" is to output just one " in the result )

Comment: What I'm actually trying to achieve is to have a picture and a description for each picture below that.  I want to have 6 cells on each row and unlimited rows.  I only put the crossover information on there, but I should have actually put the picid and picdescrip in there as well.

Comment: @user2709389: Attach a sample image of what you're trying to achieve in maybe Word or something to help us better understand your requirement.

Comment: See above for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You shuld edit your question or post comments, not edit others answers ;)
http://i.stack.imgur.com/cSEOp.jpg
You will need to create the layout first, I would create a dummy layout first in classic HTML and then apply the code generation when the wanted layout is clear.

Comment: Ok I updated the code, but I'm still having issues with the counter.  Instead of placing 5 unique images on a row and then going to the next row and placing 5 more unique images on that row it is adding 5 of the same images and then going to the next row and adding 5 more of a new set of images.  If it returns 10 values, there are 10 rows with the same images on each of the rows and not unique ones.

Comment: @user2709389 Answer updated, it should do what you want based on what you have described so far.

Comment: That code you suggested worked!!  You are amazing!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Something on the following lines:

```
Dim strTable as New StringBuilder()
strTable.Append("<table Style='border:2;border-width: 1px;'>")

For Each dr As DataRowView In dv

    Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
    Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
    Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()


    strTable.Append("<tr>")
    For j As Integer = 0 To 4
        strTable.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td>"), crossover))
    Next

    strTable.Append("</tr>")
Next

strTable.Append("</table>")
divTable.InnerHtml = strTable
```

Note the following:

1. Since you can have a large number of rows, prefer [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx) over string.
2. I don't really think you need an inner loop to construct your TDs. You'll probably have 6 different values populated per row, like picid, picdescription etc. You should simply add them with a single `StringBuilder.Append()` call.
3. If you're doing this in ASP.NET, you may better be off assigning your datasource directly to a DataGrid and writing the output html. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435218/generate-html-table-from-datagrid/18435293?noredirect=1#18435293).