# Generate HTML table from DataGrid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, datagrid

This may be plain easy, but somehow I can't think of a direct way. Is it posible to generate the HTML output (the `<TABLE>`) from a `DataGrid` object on the server-side? Something like:

```
MyDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataTable;
MyDataGrid.DataBind();
string My_HTML_Table = MyDataGrid.A_Fancy_Method_To_Generate_HTML();
```

At this point the string `My_HTML_Table` should have something like `<TABLE><TR><TD>1</TD>...</TABLE>`.

Comment: you can try datagrid.rendercontrol method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at DataGrid.RenderControl method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx

Comment: Precisely correct. One needs to create a `StringWriter` attached to a `StringBuilder` instance and then using that StringWriter, one needs to create an `XHTMLTextWriter`. This XHTMLTextWriter can then be passed to `RenderControl` method to get your output in your StringBuilder object. Thanks Sri.